# what is equivalent of closest(element) (jQuery) in YUI?

Tags: jquery, yui

Does anyone know what is equivalent of closest(element) (jQuery) in YUI library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_ancestor

ancestor(fn, testSelf, stopFn)Node

Returns the nearest ancestor that passes the test applied by supplied boolean method.
Parameters:

```
fn String | Function

A selector string or boolean method for testing elements. If a function is used, it receives the current node being tested as the only argument.
testSelf Boolean

optional Whether or not to include the element in the scan
stopFn String | Function

optional A selector string or boolean method to indicate when the search should stop. The search bails when the function returns true or the selector matches. If a function is used, it receives the current node being tested as the only argument.
```

Returns:
Node: The matching Node instance or null if not found

Comment: It's worth noting that YUI's `ancestor` is not, in itself, equivalent to jQuery's `closest`.  `closest` by default considers the current element / node, while `ancestor` requires `true` passed as a second parameter in order to include the current element.